# Board is getting reset when I lower the temperature in Thermal Chamber

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, temperature, thermal, reset

I have a board which I put in the thermal chamber.

I increase the temperature inside the thermal chamber to 85degC. Soak it for 2 hours and note some readings.

Then, when I change the temperature to 25degC from 85degC, it gets reset and then comes back to normal operation within a fraction of second.

Anyone know why this happens and what details do I need to provide to get an answer for this?

The freq used in my board are 8MHz, 32.768kHz, 248kHz, 48MHz and 125kHz

Comment: Is your thermal chamber plugged into the same thing that the board is plugged into?

Comment: No. Thermal chamber has a different power source and my board has a different power source.

Comment: How rapidly do you change the temperature?  At what point do things fail?  You are going to need to provide a whole lot more information to make this an answerable question, likely what you really have is a need to do some creative on-site debugging to "work the problem" until it is understood.

Comment: I kept the board at 85degC. Let it stay there for 2 hours. Performed my readings for 1 hour. After this, to change the temperature, I entered the 25degC and after hitting OK at 25degC, it resets for a fraction of second and then recovers

Comment: So your board resets when the cooling compressor stars? It is susceptible for electromagnetic interference?

Comment: Yes i believe. How does compressor starting enable my board to reset

Comment: Can anyone help with this

Comment: @Newbie electromagnetic interference, **literally** what Justme wrote.

Comment: Yes. Want to understand what happens when the compressor start as the EMI affect my board

Comment: You probably have some sort of coil on your board that picks up the change in the electromagnetic field and generates induced current that can generate voltage. This could be a poor layout of power lines or wires in general. I had this once with a small board where the power lines on opposite PCB edges enclosed a microcontroller. In many cases, the microcontroller was reset when the controlled wiper motor started up.

Comment: I have inductors. But they are shielded parts only 68uH and 22uH and 100uH. Then, how could they help? Could you share me the layout which you are mentioning?

Comment: Can you help with the layout and your explanation